# Webpack, generate individual CSS file for each imported CSS file with MiniCssExtractPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm new to Webpack (and dev) and am trying to figure out how to use Webpack and some plugins to separate any CSS import into an individual CSS link tag.

This is my webpack-config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: {
    index: ['./src/assets/js/script.js'],
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'assets/js/[name].bundle.js',
    assetModuleFilename: 'assets/images/[name][ext][query]',
    clean: true,
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      chunks: ['index'],
      title: "~we don't talk about bruno~",
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'assets/css/[name].css',
    }),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          // 2. remove CSS from JS and save into an external file
          { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
          // 1. generate CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        use: [
          // 3. remove CSS from JS and save into an external file
          { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
          // 2. generate CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // 1. tranpile SCSS into CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

This is my JavaScript file:

```
import '../css/style.scss';
import 'animate.css';
```

I know Webpack is a bundler and I understand it but is there a possibility to generate `index.css` and `animate.css` individually and link it to HTML? Or maybe use another plugin and specify `animate.css` on the Webpack config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

You could use `optimization` entry of `webpack.config.js`. You can add this entry in your `webpack.config.js` after `plugins` array for example:

```
optimization: {
    moduleIds: "deterministic",
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          test: /animate.css/
          name: "animate",
          type: "css/mini-extract",
          chunks: "all",
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

The above configuration would generate a separate file for `animate.css`. However it won't generate a separate CSS file per CSS file import. It's kind of the opposite of what a module bundler is made for.

## More

Often what we do is separate the code we wrote from what's coming from `node_modules`, with this config:

```
 optimization: {
    moduleIds: "deterministic",
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all",
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendors",
          chunks: "all",
        },
        styles: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendors",
          type: "css/mini-extract",
          chunks: "all",
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

This way, in addition to what you would normally have, you get `vendors.js` and `vendors.css` for what's coming from `node_modules`. See [Code Splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) on Webpack's official documentation to learn more.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read it. I saw this link, but it was too fast. It's not exactly what I expected, but I think it's a better solution.

Comment: and if the vendor code isn't in the node_module folder? Maybe I downloaded manually? than I need to edit test parameter to an array e specify the file there?

Comment: Yeah you can do that. You can change  the value of test. It should be a valid regEx, that’s it.

Comment: Glad I could share :)